# Problem with wait_order in Modelsim - unexpected keyword

Tags: system-verilog, modelsim

I'm trying to run some code from chipverify website in Modelsim and it doesn't work - and I have no idea why. Example from website is about wait_order.

```
module tb;
  // Declare three events that can be triggered separately
  event a, b, c;

  // This block triggers each event one by one
  initial begin
    #10 -> a;
    #10 -> b;
    #10 -> c;
  end

  // This block waits until each event is triggered in the given order
  initial begin

    wait_order (a,b,c) 
      $display ("Events were executed in the correct order");
    else 
        $display ("Events were NOT executed in the correct order !");  
  end
endmodule
```

I expect output:

```
Events were executed in the correct order.
```

But insted i get something like this:

```
syntax error, unexpected "SystemVerilog keyword 'wait_order'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unimplemented feature of SystemVerilog in Modelsim. Check the documentation.

SystemVerilog `sequence`s with assertions give you much of the same functionality.